# Another IE bug: stack overflow at line 0, while using jquery address or at least ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image-gallery

Hello fellow stackoverflow-ers,
I built an ajax image gallery and used asual' jquery address for the deep linking.
The error happens, right after loading the gallery, on the first onclick when clicking on the image or on all the clicks of the thumbnails.

Basically, my code on the image is:

```
<li id="thumbnail_<?php echo $row->position;?>"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:setAddress('<?php echo $row->url;?>');"><img src="<?php echo $row->filePath;?>" /></a></li>
```

my code on the thumbnails is:

```
<li id="thumbnail_<?php echo $row->position;?>"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:setAddress('<?php echo $row->url;?>');"><img src="<?php echo $row->filePath;?>" /></a></li>
```

so that when I click, I change the address in the address bar using setAddress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setAddress(address){ 
        $.address.value(address.replace(/^#/, ''));
    }
</script>
```

and then I detect the change in the address and reload the image (and thumbnails accordingly) in ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.address.change(function(event) { 
        checkAnchor();
    }); 

    function checkAnchor(){
        var albumId = <?php echo $albumId;?>;
        if($.address.value() != '' && $.address.value() != '/'){
            //get the id of the image
            var arData = $.address.value().split("-");
            var arIdExt = arData[1].split(".");
            var id = arIdExt[0];
            reloadImage(albumId,id,'0','curr');
        }else{
            reloadImage(albumId,id,'1','curr');
        }
    }

    function reloadImage(albumId, photoId, position, action){
    $("#imgLoading").show();
    var visibleThumbnails = <?php echo $visibleThumbnails;?>;
    var albumName = $("#albumName").val();
    $.post('/montreal/inc/ajax/changeImage.php',{albumId:albumId, photoId:photoId, position:position, action:action}, function(data){
        //data + photoposition=[url]
        var arData = data.split("photoposition=");
        if(position == 0){
            position = jQuery.trim(arData[1]);
        }

        $("#photo-details").html(arData[0]);
        $.address.title(albumName+" - Photo #"+position);
        $("#imgLoading").hide();

        //reload the thumbnails
        if(action == 'next'){               
            var maxThumbnails = <?php echo count($album->arPhotos['photos']);?>;
            var nextPosition = position+1;
            var currentRow = Math.ceil(position/visibleThumbnails);
            if(nextPosition > maxThumbnails){ nextPosition = 1;}                            
            if(position%visibleThumbnails == 0 || position == maxThumbnails){
                reloadThumbnails(currentRow,visibleThumbnails,albumId,nextPosition,'next');
            }else{//fix the activeposition of the reloadThumbnails
                reloadThumbnails(currentRow,visibleThumbnails,albumId,nextPosition,'curr');
            }               
        }else if(action == 'curr'){
            var maxThumbnails = <?php echo count($album->arPhotos['photos']);?>;
            var currentRow = Math.ceil(position/visibleThumbnails);
            reloadThumbnails(currentRow,visibleThumbnails,albumId,position,'curr');
        }
    },"html"  
);
```

}
    
The "stack overflow at line 0" appears right after the click and before the setaddress, so that I am pretty confused as to where it could come from. After clicking on the error message, nothing happens, and after clicking on the image again, the gallery actually works. But if I click on the thumbnails, the error appears, but if I click on the thumbnails again, the error still appears.

As far as I've read, this error is way generic and is usually caused by a loop or a recursion. But I cannot see one, especially when I can see it happen only on the first click in the gallery.

Anyone has a hint as to where I should search?

Example of the error: 
http://www.ckoi.com/montreal/photos/gala-des-gemeaux-tapis-rouge-194/

EDIT:
After some tests, I realized that the error actually happens right after I loaded my page. Anywhere I click, I get a stack overflow. So that I am even more confused... But maybe it's because I load the gallery a first time in ajax? I'll investigate

Comment: get rid of the javascript: in the onclick event. The label is useless there.

Comment: When page loads there is a 404 with an Ajax call in both browsers. Seems to generate an error with IE http://www.ckoi.com/nowplaying/clean_ckoi_montreal.xml

Comment: Since `checkAnchor()` is your URL change function, my guess is that something in `checkAnchor()` causes `checkAnchor()` to get called again, probably in `reloadImage()` which ends up causing infinite recursion.  There's too much minimized code for me to step through the relevant parts to go further.

Comment: It seems to happen because your are trying to display an image that has not quite finished being preloaded.  If you wait a few seconds before clicking thumbnails this popup doesn't occur.  Also - it is a popup, a javascript alert that displays "stack overflow at line 0" - it is not a javascript error.  One of your javascript components/ie addons is trapping the error and displaying the alert.  Perhaps search through your js files looking for "alert".

Comment: @epascarello: I removed it to have: 
    <li id="thumbnail_<?php echo $row->position;?>"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="setAddress('<?php echo $row->url;?>');"><img src="<?php echo $row->filePath;?>" /></a></li>
but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @jfriend00 : I added my reloadImage function to my first post. I do not call checkAnchor, nor do I change the address again. It really is just a normal ajax that reloads the image and the thumbnails.

Comment: IE often throws stack overflows when too much recursion / function calls are happening. Try putting delays on any and all function calls (say about 100 ms). And then, if that gets rid of it, remove them in chunks until you find which ones are causing it.

Comment: @James: I'm wondering if it could really be a like you say: to display an image that has not finished preloading, since the error occurs before I even call my function reloadImage.
I'll look for the alert in my javascripts, though. I'll keep you posted

Comment: @Marshall: I tried putting a delay on the action of the setAddress (since setAddress is the first function called when I click), but it didn't even get called before the alert with the stack overflow appeared. So I'm still searching.

Comment: @James: I tried searching for "alert" in all the javascripts on the page, but I couldn't find any.

For some reason, it seems like it comes from the onclick itself or something. I tried replacing my setAddress call in the onclick by an alert and it still gave me the error...
*scratches head* aaah, I love IE so much...

Comment: @ether Your answer should be below, as an actual answer.

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg: I can't for now. Since I'm new I must wait for at least 4 hours or write my answer in the post, like it was suggested by the site.

Comment: well congrats on finding/solving the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the original poster:

Ok, I found it. I'm really not sure why this was causing such trouble for IE, but here it was:

In order to keep track of the album title and not to have to get it in every one of my ajax calls, I kept it in an invisible text input :

```
<input id="albumName" type="text" style="display:none;" value="<?php echo $album->name;?>"/>
```

If the title had double spaces in that hidden input, IE was complaining... To me, this makes no sense, but now it works...

Thanks guys for your insights! Hopes this helps someone else to debug IE....